# Get the last record for each createdAt

Tags: python, django

I have this like models

```
class Ticket(UpdateCreateDate):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="user"
    )

    bus = models.ForeignKey(
        Bus, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="bus_tickets"
    )

    PDA= models.ForeignKey(
        Material, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="terminal"
    )

    geolocalisation = models.ForeignKey(
        Geolocalisation,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="geolocalisation",
    )
```

i want to get that format

```
{
    "today"[{
        "itineraire":"Upn - Gare-centrale",
        "PDA":"PDA-13",
        "Bus":"TB200",
        "Driver":"Mr Landu",
        "date":"20/01/2023",
        "vente-par-cash":"30",
        "pu":"30",
    }],
      "yesterday"[{
        "itineraire":"Upn - Gare-centrale",
        "PDA":"PDA-13",
        "Bus":"TB210",
        "Driver":"Mr Bob",
        "date":"20/01/2023",
        "vente-par-cash":"30",
        "pu":"30",
    }]
}
```

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: If you each time want the latest, then why should the keys map on a *list* of dictionaries, and not just a single dictionary?